# MySql Limit results per grouping in query with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
select distinct 
    loc.mID, 
    loc.city, 
    loc.state, 
    loc.zip, 
    loc.country, 
    loc.latitude, 
    loc.longitude, 
    baseInfo.firstname, 
    baseInfo.lastname, 
    baseInfo.profileimg, 
    baseInfo.facebookID, 
    (((acos(sin(('37.8068406'*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(('37.8068406'*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((('-121.3062367' - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance`, teams.teamName, teams.leagueType, teams.teamType, teams.subcat 
FROM memb_geo_locations loc 
left join memb_friends friends on (friends.mID = loc.mID or friends.friendID = loc.mID) and (friends.mID = '100019' or friends.friendID = '100019') 
join memb_baseInfo baseInfo on baseInfo.mID = loc.mID 
join memb_teams teams on teams.mID = loc.mID
where 
    loc.primaryAddress = '1' and ((friends.mID is null or friends.friendID is null) or (friends.isactive = 2)) 
and 
    (teams.teamName like '%Buffalo Bills%' or teams.teamName like '%New England Patriots%' or teams.teamName like '%Dallas Cowboys%')
and 
    loc.mID != 100019 
having 
    `distance` < 50 
order by baseInfo.firstname asc limit 30
```

Which works perfectly for my core needs. However I am trying to firgure out how I can take the query and refine it so the part that is

```
(teams.teamName like '%Buffalo Bills%' or teams.teamName like '%New England Patriots%' or teams.teamName like '%Dallas Cowboys%')
```

will each yield a max defined amount of results per team name (less or none per is fine to, just seeking a max per), while having a max output of the limit specified at the end of the query. Is there anyway I can refine this query to do what I am hoping? Someone told me in another recent post similar to this that I made to check out `UNION` but I am not sure how that would apply to this query? Assuming that is the right direction to go.

Comment: Can you explain what the query does and what exactly you want to add to the query? I can probably solve that but don't understand what the outcome should be (Btw, are you confident about the scalability of your query?)

Comment: Your query will be extremely slow on large database. instead of using a method to calculate a radius, use a square where Latitude>X and Latitude < X2 and Long > Y and Long < Y2 .... or use a Fulltext search engine capable of GeoLocation search like Sphinx or Solr.

Comment: Shehabix, wouldn't that assume I have 2 and 2 for lat/lon? Currently I have a single lat/lon pair to work with, and I am attempting to find those who are in a proximity there of. However I might be interested in knowing more about Sphinx or Solr that you mention? Currently I only have lat/lon sets to work with would that work for me?

Comment: Thomas what the above query does now. Is its finding people in my DB who are within proximity of one another who share common interests, in this case teams from sports, however this can be anything as we have a vast set of categories. Anyway the goal is to have the output group-able by what ever the category is, and to limit those results to x. So each time we pull for results we are guaranteed say 3 groups with 3 results per (or less if no or limited matches are found) Rather than have a group with 10 results, another with 5 and another with 15. Does that help?

Comment: In the above example, there are 3 teams, so 3 groups, of which I do not want more than for sake of example 3 results per grouping. Where as currently I am getting whatever matches first, so If I have 10 from the top that are one group, 5 from there in the other group and 15 from there in the other group, Ill top off at my max limit of 30, but my results per will be staggered and thats not the desire. Sorry Im not great with words and trying to describe things